# Computer freezes when loading .gltf model in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf, parcel

I am running an Ubuntu 20.10 machine and testing my site on Firefox. Using npm as package manager and parcel as a bundler. When I try to load a .gltf model in three.js, parcel does not show any errors. When I go to localhost:1234/ my laptop freezes and the canvas is blank.

The directory structure and the file links in `index.html` and `index.js` are correct, so that's not an issue. I am also using `parcel-plugin-static-files-copy` to ensure the static file is available. Also, I generated the .gltf file using Blender and know that it's a valid json.

Code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>chtnnh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(
  "../static/tvSet.gltf",
  (gltf) => {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
  },
  undefined,
  (err) => {
    console.error("Could not load asset " + err);
  }
);

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1, 500);
light.position.set(100, 0, 250);
scene.add(light);

camera.position.z = 5;

function threeJsResize() {
  // ensures scene is responsive
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function animate() {
  // renders the scene at the fps of the machine
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();

// add event listener for responsive three.js
window.addEventListener("resize", threeJsResize);
```

style.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "x",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "x"
  ],
  "author": "x",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "parcel": "^1.12.4",
    "three": "^0.125.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-plugin-static-files-copy": "^2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Edit:

I tried following various tutorials as well. This one seems to work out, but I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated

Code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>chtnnh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#c");
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2; // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color("black");

  {
    const planeSize = 40;

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load(
      "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/checker.png"
    );
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    const repeats = planeSize / 2;
    texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);

    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -0.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const skyColor = 0xb1e1ff; // light blue
    const groundColor = 0xb97a20; // brownish orange
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(skyColor, groundColor, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xffffff;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(5, 10, 2);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(light.target);
  }

  function frameArea(sizeToFitOnScreen, boxSize, boxCenter, camera) {
    const halfSizeToFitOnScreen = sizeToFitOnScreen * 0.5;
    const halfFovY = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(camera.fov * 0.5);
    const distance = halfSizeToFitOnScreen / Math.tan(halfFovY);
    // compute a unit vector that points in the direction the camera is now
    // in the xz plane from the center of the box
    const direction = new THREE.Vector3()
      .subVectors(camera.position, boxCenter)
      .multiply(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1))
      .normalize();

    // move the camera to a position distance units way from the center
    // in whatever direction the camera was from the center already
    camera.position.copy(direction.multiplyScalar(distance).add(boxCenter));

    // pick some near and far values for the frustum that
    // will contain the box.
    camera.near = boxSize / 100;
    camera.far = boxSize * 100;

    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    // point the camera to look at the center of the box
    camera.lookAt(boxCenter.x, boxCenter.y, boxCenter.z);
  }

  {
    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    gltfLoader.load(
      "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/cartoon_lowpoly_small_city_free_pack/scene.gltf",
      (gltf) => {
        const root = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(root);

        // compute the box that contains all the stuff
        // from root and below
        const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(root);

        const boxSize = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).length();
        const boxCenter = box.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());

        // set the camera to frame the box
        frameArea(boxSize * 0.5, boxSize, boxCenter, camera);

        // update the Trackball controls to handle the new size
        controls.maxDistance = boxSize * 10;
        controls.target.copy(boxCenter);
        controls.update();
      }
    );
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out there was nothing wrong with the first `index.js` that I have mentioned in the question. The model was too high poly for my machine, because when I linked a low poly model the page loaded just fine.

Working code:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>chtnnh</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(
  "https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/cartoon_lowpoly_small_city_free_pack/scene.gltf",
  (gltf) => {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
  },
  undefined,
  (err) => {
    console.error("Could not load asset " + err);
  }
);

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1, 500);
light.position.set(100, 0, 250);
scene.add(light);

camera.position.z = 5;

function threeJsResize() {
  // ensures scene is responsive
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function animate() {
  // renders the scene at the fps of the machine
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();

// add event listener for responsive three.js
window.addEventListener("resize", threeJsResize);
```